# Where is the proguard mapping file in Android studio

Tags: android

In android studio(2.2.2) where are the proguard mapping files generated after generating a signed APK?

I have Generated Signed Apk file and follow below two paths but in my root folder i did not get any "mapping.txt" file

```
For debug: \app\build\outputs\mapping\debug\mapping.txt

For release: \app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt
```

please suggest me how can i get this "mapping.txt" file?

Comment: The path looks correct. Just to confirm, is ProGuard definitely enabled for the build types and flavours that are being built as a result of running a build via the "Generate Signed APK..." task?

Comment: "but in my root folder" - if you mean the `build` on the root level, that's a wrong place. They are in the `build` folder under your app module.

Answer (score 4):

Do you has been generate proguard mapping ?

in `proguard-rules.pro` 
type it `-printmapping {location}/filename.txt` .

example :

For debug

```
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/debug/mapping.txt
```

For release

```
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```